# Dividing the texts on Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, uitextview

Dividing the texts on Text View/Label in order to be opened in a different modal when clicking on individual sentences.

Etc: according to full stop.

Text in Text View/Label was pulled over via sqlite. I draw data with sqlite and I combine the texts into paragraphs. I want information about that statement to be printed when every sentence is printed. The application is written in swift 4, XCode 9 environment.

Etc article: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ut dui a velit bibendum tincidunt ac non eros. Maecenas vel risus molestie, ultrices turpis quis, mattis lorem. Suspendisse quis ultrices sem.

Separate clicks for all text:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
- Duis ut dui a velit bibendum tincidunt ac non eros.
- Maecenas vel risus molestie, ultrices turpis quis, mattis lorem.
- Suspendisse quis ultrices sem.

The text needs to be in paragraph format. This is an article. My purpose is not to show it in the form of separate cues. My purpose is to connect each event separately to each event.

I used FRHyperLabel but not working... FRHyperLabel in scroolview. The click is working but it works wrong. For example; I'm clicking the 2nd sentence, but it's acting like 1st sentence.

```
for eleman in articleSentenceList{
    let handler = {
        (hyperLabel: FRHyperLabel?, substring: String?) -> Void in

        let controller = UIAlertController(title: substring, message: eleman.v1, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let denemeString:String = eleman.v2

    let substring = denemeString[denemeString.startIndex..<denemeString.index(denemeString.startIndex, offsetBy: denemeString.count)]

    translateList.append(String(substring))

    txtTitle.setLinksForSubstrings([translateList.last!], withLinkHandler: handler)

}
```

Comment: Should the bullet points be added to the resulting string? and put each separate string be put in a button? Could make the desired output clearer?

Comment: bullet: just to show you. Of course. Break up the text -> Add a link -> Combine

Comment: What should the link do? And what do you mean by "combine"?

Comment: I have text and translate. I want to show the translation in modal by clicking on the sentence.

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried so far

Comment: like android ClickableSpan

Comment: I did not write anything for swift. I had written for android.

Comment: You have to use `NSAttributtedString` with anchors and put it to a `UITextView`. That's the easist way to do it anyway. A second possibility is to handle the touch yourself and use core text to check which letter/word/sentence has been drawn at that specific position.

Comment: I've tried FRHyperLabel. I added the codes in question.